# R101 with mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

Essentially I have a table with different columns, of interest in this case is gender

| Gender |
| --- |
| Male |
| Female |

I'd like to create a new column called gender_num that sets all male to 0 and all female to 1. I tried to use if df['Gender] == 'Male' , 0 , else, 1 type deal but r doesn't like that with strings that have more than 1 value. I know that you can use dyplr and the mutate function but I'm very confused. How could you get the df to look something like this via generating a new column.

| Gender | Gender_num |
| --- | --- |
| Male | 0 |
| Female | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

From one new user to another, Try adding your code to generate a sample table next time so people can work off work you've already done. Also, you might get down-voted for lack of research as this is a common sub-chapter in many intro texts. You can see an example chapter [here](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Emjbrydon/tutorials/BAinR/recode.html#recode-a-text-column-to-a-dummy).

Aside from that, lets say you have 10 observations of male female.

`df <- tibble::as.tibble(x= rep(1:10))`

`gendf <-df %>% mutate(gender=sample(x=c("male","female"), 10, replace=TRUE))`

You can then run a mutate to add a your categorical numeric variable.

`gendf <- gendf %>% mutate(gender_dummy=if_else(gender=="female",1,0))`

Note: since the original character variable has two values, me using `if_else()` is the simplest way.

But you can use `recode()` too as you can add as many values as you like.

`gendf <- gendf %>% mutate(gender_dummy2= recode(gender,"female" = 1, "male"=0))`

[You should get this resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt7m2.png)

From there I would add value labels and call it a day.